# AD v2.0 Endpoint HTTP redirect url

Tags: http, authentication, azure-active-directory

We are using an internal website using HTTP. I want to use AD v2.0 for authentication. I've created the app/registration and everything works fine with localhost.
The issue I'm having is that the dev app portal doesn't allow HTTP redirect urls.

I have tested a couple of "twisted" workarounds:

- having a local Node.js http-server to redirect from a https to http
- By using the Requestly Chrome extension

Is there any viable workaround with no overhead, aside having to setup the server to use https?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today it is not supported and there is no officially recommended workaround. As you mentioned there are some extensions you can use for this, or you can use the 1.0 endpoint. Microsoft does not support transmitting tokens over unsecured channel. Currently, apps that are registered in the Application Registration Portal are restricted to a limited set of redirect URI values. The redirect URI for web apps and services must begin with the scheme https.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison